# Making request from client application (ReactJs+NodeJs) to Java web service

Tags: java, node.js, web-services, reactjs, express

I have separate application for client side which is in ReactJs and NodeJS (Express server) and Web Services in Java application running in tomcat.

My query is which is better approach in terms of making web service call.

1. One is making direct web service call from ReactJS and get the data.
2. Other one is calling web service in Express server. Request from client browser will go to Express and Express will make all web services call.

I know one issue in making direct call to web service will be cross domain policy which can be handle by setting configuration in Java server.

Apart from it what should be better approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my experience it ended up better using direct calls from UI application and avoiding intermediate server.

Reason for doing this directly is that our servers ended up with a lot of restrictions based on IP addresses, and all requests have been coming from intermediate server (nodeJS server), so DDOS protection of end server had to have some exceptions (our node server which could be on ACS with dynamic IP addresses so it might be hard to manage).

Also If you want to pass and track end users IP addresses, you need to manage headers on Node server (to be sure you are passing it as it was in original request).

It is way simpler to manage this kind of situation if calls are comming from React app and simply set up CORS on java server.

Also its way easier to debug it on UI app directly, so you will be watching response logs on one place only. Other way around you could end up debugging your node server and UI app.

Hope this helps a bit.

Answer (score 0):

Best way IMO is to create a router in Node js specifically for all your Java webservices and act as a proxy.

Suppose if your url pattern is like `http://domain/java-ws/api` then all these requests will be routed to your Java service.

If you have an Apache server directing requests to your node JS then configure url pattern proxy using proxy module.

Browsers are blocking CORS requests for a reason. You may get away by setting things on your server.